# Magento Attribute Value

Tags: magento, attributes

I have defined one attribute set named looks. Inside this there is one attribute style with attribute code 'style'. This attribute has 9 values. How do I get these values?
I have so far done this:

```
public function styleAction(){
    $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code', 'style' )->getFirstItem();
    var_dump( $attribute);
```

This doesn't gives me correct result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a product and from this product you want to get an attribute.

- Get attr from product

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(<ProductID>);
$my_attribute = $product->getAttributeName(); // i. e. $product->getStyle()
```

So you need to get you product first, and then you can get the value of an attribute set for this product.

You can load all values of a product like so:

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load(<attributeId>);
$attributeOptions = $attribute->setStoreId($storeId)->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
```

Comment: without product, there is no way?

Comment: You want just a list of possible values a specific attribute? I don't understand why you just want to have this attribute w/o a product

Comment: This attribute is acting as a filter. I need to show all the values of this filter

Comment: I edited my answer to show how you can load all options of an attribute. Hope this helps.